# How to exclude multiples folders from MyPy checking by using pyproject.toml conf?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, pyproject.toml

Python version : 3.8
MyPy version : 0.95

Hello,
I'm using a pyproject.toml to handle my MyPy configuration.
I had a working configuration until i tried to add another folder to exclude from the MyPy checking.
I've tried many things, none of them worked...

I had this in my pyproject.toml :

```
[tool.mypy]
explicit_package_bases = true
files = [
  "my_project",
  "tests"
]
exclude = [
    'venv'
]
namespace_packages = true
no_implicit_optional = true
python_executable = "venv/bin/python3"
python_version = 3.8
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_configs = true
warn_unused_ignores = false
```

I've tried this :

```
# Example 1
exclude = [
    'venv',
    'models'
]

# Example 2
exclude = [
    'venv',
    'my_project/core/models'
]


# Example 3
exclude = [
    'venv',
    '^my_project/core/models/.'
]

# And so on...
```

The example 3 is a try because of [the documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-exclude)

No matter what, 'my_project/core/models' folder is never ignored... Can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong please ?

***EDIT :***
As SUTerliakov mentionned in the comment doing this worked (it's a conflict between files and exclude) :

```py
[[tool.mypy.overrides]]
module = [
  "my_project.core.models.*"
]
ignore_errors = true
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, the mess of how different linters and checkers handle exclude/ignore files and errors is awful. I suppose that there is a conflict of `files` and `exclude` in your case. If so, you can use `[[tool.mypy.overrides]]` for `module = "my_project.core.models"` and set `ignore_errors = True` in that section.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11760)